# How to configure WinUAE fire keys to work in different ways? (autofire on/off)

Tags: emulation, amiga, winuae

I'm trying to configure WinUAE to be able to use the <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> for non-autofire and <kbd>RAlt</kbd> for autofire. Here is how my config screen looks like:

[image]

My problem is that if I change **Autofire** to any value it will be overwritten by the value on this screen:

[image]

What can I do to be able to configure my two keys: <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> and <kbd>RAlt</kbd> to work in different ways?

I'm asking this here because I've googled it and I can see that others have this problem as well but no answer is provided so far.

Answer (score 1):

Please set the autofire for Port 2 to "No autofire". Curiously otherwise it won't work for me.

[image]

In the Input tab select RMENU. In the dropdown select "2", then reassign the "Joy2 Fire" and click in the Autofire column until "yes". et voilà.

[image]